# Windows 2012 server without gui

Tags: user-interface, telnet, windows-server-2012

I have a Windows 2012 server from a VPS and I RDP to it to manage.
Due to low memory, I want to remove the UI infrastructure and only use remote telnet.
For this I have the Telnet server switched on and can verify I can remotely access it.
When I remove user interface feature from server manager, it's asking me to remove Telnet server as well as Powershell both I need for remote administering.

How do I achieve this goal?

**Edit1**: I tried via remove features option from server manager.

I have an Amazon EC2 instance. I could not find there an option to launch a server core instance

Comment: What commands exactly are you using to remove these features?  Update your question to reflect this new information.

Comment: Windows cannot run without graphics mode. I doubt Server Core would give you the improvements you want. It still runs a GUI, after all. It’s just `cmd` instead of Explorer.

Comment: @Ramhound Updated

Comment: @DanielB Could you comment on edits?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use Minimal Server Interface to see if still doing the same?
in a case you dont know how
To configure  Server with a GUI installation to use the Minimal
Server Interface, you must remove the Server Graphical Shell feature by using Windows
PowerShell or the Remove Roles And Features Wizard